# Expected an indented block in nested if statements in Python

Tags: python

I had checked it several times but it still says **expected an indented block** at `if (root.right.left is not None) or (root.right.right is not None)`

```
class Solution(object):
    def sumOfLeftLeaves(self,root):
        if root.val is None:
            return 0
        elif root.left is None and root.right is not None:
            return self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right)
        elif root.left is not None and root.right is None:
            return self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left)
        elif root.left is not None and root.right is not None:
            if root.left.left is None and root.left.right is None:
                if (root.right.left is not None) or (root.right.right is not None):
                    return root.left.val + self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right)
                else:
                    return root.left.val
            else:
                return (self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left)+self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right))
        else:
            return 0
```

Help please.

Comment: traceback please.

Comment: Did you by any chance mix up tabs and spaces?

Comment: You have mixed tabs and spaces; run with `python -tt` to flush them out. I see `return self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left)` and `if root.left.left is None and root.left.right is None:` both have a tab.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How to run with 'python -tt'?

Comment: @CYC: how do you run your Python code right now?

Comment: It is probably easier to just have your editor replace all tabs with spaces.

Comment: @ChristianDean: that's an excellent post, duped.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just type "python filename.py" in terminal...